# Minors of a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, symbolic, education

I'm trying to get the minors of a symbolic matrix, but it doesn't work (I'd like to use the first command below to create the matrix, not other commands). Can you tell me why and how to fix it?

```
B = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
Minors[B]
```

[image]

---

EDIT: I know that also the determinant of the (square) matrix itself is a minor, but Mathematica does not provide it. Why?

Comment: It is actually correct. Read carefully the definition in help.  `For an n*n matrix the (i,j)^th element of Minors[m] gives the determinant of the matrix obtained by deleting the (n-i+1)^th row and the (n-j+1)^th column of m.` So for 2 by 2,  i.e. n=2, the (1,1) entry in the minor, matrix returned is the determinant of the matrix when removing the SECOND row and the SECOND column. Which is your case is `a`. And for entry (1,2) will be the determinant of the matrix when removing SECOND row and FIRST column, which is `b` and so on.

Comment: Hello @Nasser the problem is that the determinant of the matrix is a minor, but Mathematica does not provide it. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Minors` does indeed work on symbolic matrices. However, the position of elements might be different than usual. Read the reference page for [`Minors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html):

> - For an $n\times n$ matrix the $(i,j)^{th}$ element of `Minors[m]` gives the determinant of the matrix obtained by **deleting the $(n-i+1)^{th}$ row and the $(n-j+1)^{th}$ column of `m`**.
> - `Map[Reverse,Minors[m],{0,1}]` makes the $(i,j)^{th}$ element correspond to deleting the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column of m.

So what you probably want is:

```
B = {{a, b}, {c, d}};

Map[Reverse, Minors[B], {0, 1}]

(* {{d, c}, {b, a}} *)
```

Comment: Hello @Domen the strange thing is that also the determinant of the matrix itself is a minor, but Mathematica does not provide it. Why?

Comment: @Gennaro, you need to specify the *second* argument of `Minors[]`: `With[{n = 5}, Minors[Array[C, {n, n}], n] == {{Det[Array[C, {n, n}]]}}]`.

Comment: Domen, you don't need to map `Reverse`: `Reverse[Minors[B], {1, 2}]`

Comment: Hello @M.'storpos I have some difficult to get your command, can you explain it please?

Comment: @Gennaro, look at the doc page for `Minors[]` and pay attention to what it says about the *second* argument.

Comment: Thank you very much @M.'storpos now it's clear; could you tell me how to get with a single command all the minor by varying $k$ from $n=2$ to $1$ please?